# How to install crebs on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: software-installation, 14.10, crebs

I was trying to install [crebs](http://www.obfuscatepenguin.net/crebs/) earlier. sadly the ppa is dead or is not working, so i downloaded the source code and followed the instruction by running setup.sh as root, after that i typed "crebs" into the terminal and the following error came:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/crebs", line 38, in <module>
from crebs.main import main
File "/usr/local/bin/../share/crebs/lib/crebs/main.py", line 4, in <module>
from crebs.cli          import cli
File "/usr/local/bin/../share/crebs/lib/crebs/cli.py", line 6, in <module>
from crebs.imagelists   import create_image_list
File "/usr/local/bin/../share/crebs/lib/crebs/imagelists.py", line 7, in <module>
from crebs.slideshows   import is_slideshow_file, import_slideshow
File "/usr/local/bin/../share/crebs/lib/crebs/slideshows.py", line 5, in <module>
import libxml2
ImportError: No module named libxml2
```

When I try to run:`sudo apt-get install libxml2`  I get:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libxml2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says "No module named libxml2". So I assume that this software depends on it, but as you installed it without using a package manager, the dependency couldn't be satisfied automatically.

So you can ask APT to show you packages related to libxml2 using

```
apt-cache search libxml2
```

which will give you a list of packages and short descriptions. As you will be able to see, there is a match named: `python-libxml2 - Python bindings for the GNOME XML library`.

Install it using `sudo apt-get install python-libxml2` and then retry executing the software you installed manually. If further dependency errors occur, try to solve them as described.